# Requiring a language file

Tags: javascript, internationalization, requirejs, js-amd

I'm writing an AMD internationalization module. It exports a single function that receives a string to translate and returns the translation, in a fashion similar to gettext.

I need to load the appropriate translation file from within said module, but it has to be done synchronously and with respect to a definition in the settings module.

**How can I require a module synchronously and then require another module, also synchronously?**

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you see code that uses RequireJS and *appears* to run synchronously, that's just *appearance*. For instance, you may see:

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    var foo = require("foo");
    // ...
});
```

and think that `require("foo")` is just a synchronous call. In a sense, it *is* synchronous because it returns a value immediately. However, what you don't see is that the module definition is processed as if it were:

```
define(["require", "exports", "module", "foo"], function (require, exports, module) {
    var foo = require("foo");
    // ...
});
```

The module `foo` was loaded asynchronously before RequireJS ran the callback passed to `define`, so `require("foo")` is not really asynchronous. It just looks this way.

One upshot of how these pseudo-synchronous calls work is that you cannot generally call `require(x)` where `x` is a **string** computed at run time. (Note that you *can* call `require(x)` where `x` is an **array** computed at run time, and can be followed by an optional callback. This is the "regular" asynchronous `require`. No problem here.) I said "generally" because there are cases where it can work. For instance, if you have a known and small set of possible values for `x`, you *could* define your module like this:

```
define(["a", "b", "c"], function () {
    var x = something(); // Where something() can be only return "a", "b", or "c".
    var module_x = require(x); 
    // ...
});
```

This would work because I'm listing all possible modules I might want to use in the dependencies of the `define` call, and because `something()` can only return the name of a module that is already loaded. In cases where the set is unknown ahead of time or requiring all possible modules would defeat the purpose of modularization, then you can't do this. I'd expect that in the case of an internationalization module, you would not want to load all languages so you could not do this.

RequireJS, by itself, won't work here.

What you could do is have your internationalization module return promises instead of strings. Or there may be a plugin out there that could help but I would not know about it.